# Chartjs: I only want left and right padding in pie chart

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I have a case at work where I want to use a pie chart. For this I use Chart.js (with react-chartjs-2 library as a wrapper).

I would like to have padding left and right in the canvas, but for some reason I always get top padding as well in that case, even when I specifically type top: 0. Does anyone know why this happens and what would be a way to have only padding left and right?

```
const options = {
  layout: {
    padding: {
      left: 100,
      right: 100,
      top: 0,
    }
  }
}
```

Code is below and Code Sandbox is added as well:

https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-stallman-x18qku?file=/src/App.js:0-1120

[image]

```
    import "./styles.css";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import { Chart as ChartJS, ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend } from "chart.js";
import { Pie } from "react-chartjs-2";

ChartJS.register(ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend);

export const data = {
  labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "# of Votes",
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
        "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
        "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
        "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
        "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
        "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)"
      ],
      borderColor: [
        "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
        "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
        "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
        "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
        "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)"
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }
  ]
};

const options = {
  layout: {
    padding: {
      left: 100,
      right: 100,
      top: 0,
    }
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Box>
      <Pie data={data} options={options} />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [maintainAspectRatio](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html#configuration-options) to false.

```
const options = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  layout: {
    padding: {
      left: 100,
      right: 100
    }
  }
}
```